# using pgfplotsinvokeforeach with addplot table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this minimal file:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotstableset{
  header=true,
  trim cells=true,
  col sep=comma,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{a.dat}
x,y
1,2
2,4
3,6
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{b.dat}
x,y
1,3
2,6
3,9
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread{a.dat}{\DataA}
\pgfplotstableread{b.dat}{\DataB}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table[x=x,y=y]\DataA;\label{plt:dataA}
    \addplot table[x=x,y=y]\DataB;\label{plt:dataB}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the actual file has many more input files, but for each I have one line with `\addplot`. Now I thought, instead of having many lines of `\addplot` I could use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` to call it.

something like this:

```
...
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{A,B}{
  \addplot table[x=x,y=y]\Data#1;\label{plt:data#1}
}
...
```

the label part works as expected, and the `\Data#1` part does not (also as expected). I tried some combinations of `\csname` and `\endcsname` but had no success.

how can I use this loop structure to add multiple plots from multiple tables?

Comment: Maybe you can use the files directly: `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{a,b}{\addplot table[x=x,y=y]{#1.dat};\label{plt:data:#1}}`?

Comment: @Garonenur, did the trick of esdd help you or do you need further assistance? In the first case I would vote to close this question as being solved.

Comment: @StefanPinnow sorry, I missed this comment - I will check it and close this ASAP, maybe add his comment as an answer to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to @esdd,

his answer in the comments to this question works for this mwe.
One can simply use

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{a,b}{\addplot table[x=x,y=y]{#1.dat};\label{plt:data:#1}}
```

The filename directly.